# Does header files affect on memory or processing speed of programs?

Tags: c++

I'm kind of afraid of adding many header files(like ctype.h etc.) in my programs.

And I'm curious if the header files really affect much on program's process speed or memory

Comment: Code and data also affect process speed and memory. Best to avoid either of those, too.

Comment: I don't understand why people are downvoting this. It's a valid question for beginners.

Comment: What kind of programs do you intend to write? For what kind of computers (desktops, or very cheap embedded systems)?

Comment: @ArthurM. that question might be perhaps more appropriate on http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/ than here. But is is also an opinion based one.

Answer (score 4):

The short answer:  don't worry about it.

The code and data in a program (i.e. what it does) is the main driver of program performance characteristics (speed, memory usage, etc).   The organisation of that code (e.g. what declarations are in header files for reuse, what standard headers are included) has little or no effect.

(Of course:  it is possible to craft a header file in a way that causes impacts on program performance.  But that is a result of bad programming technique, not an intrinsic problem with header files).

Common sense suggests it is prudent to only `#include` a header file if it is needed.   For example, don't `#include`  every standard header in a compilation unit (aka source file) that only needs a couple of them.     Practically, doing such a thing is unlikely to affect program speed or memory usage though.   It CAN markedly increase compilation times, since it forces the preprocessor to read and process the content of headers that are not needed.   Even then, some compiler implementation techniques (e.g. precompiled headers) can mitigate that impact as well.  In the end, there is no point in losing sleep worrying about having `#include`d three standard headers, if the compilation unit only depends on two of them.

Code that `#include`s many headers unnecessarily will usually not have any notable effect on program memory usage, speed, or other performance measures.   Although, strictly speaking, a quality of implementation concern (i.e. how good is the compiler?), most compilers avoid writing unused declarations to an object file, so there is no effect on the executable.    Most compilers - both ancient and modern - do a decent job with this.

Noting the caveat above (avoid `#include`ing a header that is not actually needed), it is therefore not worth worrying about including "many" header files.   In C++, the opposite problem (not `#include`ing a header that is actually needed) is actually worse - because it will cause any code which relies on declarations in that header file to be rejected by the compiler.

It is technically possible to write - by hand - needed declarations into a source file, rather than including a header.   However, that sort of thing becomes an unmaintainable mess very quickly (consider the effort of keeping 10 source files up to date, if the the programmer has to manually provide needed declarations in each one, rather than including headers). Avoiding that sort of problem is one of the reasons that header files exist, and are used, in the first place.

Comment: You should add that it could only be in line if you're paying attention to micro-optimizations.

Answer (score 1):

Header files are artefacts at the source code level.

Executable programs don't know about header files (or even source files). Header files are included by the [preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) (and you need to understand what the preprocessor is doing).

> I'm kind of afraid of adding many header files(like ctype.h etc.) in my programs.

Why are you afraid of that? Quite often, using many header files affect the compilation time (which you can afford spending).

> And I'm curious if the header files really affect much on program's process speed or memory

Not really. However, most [libraries](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Library_%28computing%29) are defining their interface in header files. By using a library, you indeed increase the size of your program (or of your process), but you leverage on the features and functionalities provided by that library.

---

Notice also that today, development time usually matters a lot more than execution time. In many cases, the development cost (the cost of your labor) is more important that the cost of the computer running the software (but of course there are exceptions to this rule of thumb). And software costs more than the hardware running it (again, there are exceptions to this)

<sup>(this has not been always true: in the 1950s and 1960s, computers cost much more than the developers coding programs for them. In 1960s, a mainframe could cost more than the lifetime salary of its developer; in 1987 my Sun3/160 workstation costed about 3 years of my salary; today, my powerful Linux desktop PC costs two weeks of my salary)</sup>

Because quite often software costs a lot to be developed (again, you'll find many exceptions to this) and deployed, it makes sense to try to reuse software components (to decrease development costs). Read about [COTS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commercial_off-the-shelf) & [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software). In practice, choosing the right libraries is an essential part of the software development work. Read about [component-based software engineering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component-based_software_engineering). Of course, algorithms still matter a lot (read [*Introduction to Algorithms*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Algorithms)), much more than raw code size.

At last, current (desktop, server, laptop) computers have quite a lot of memory (typically 8 or 16 gigabytes of RAM at least, and often much more) and have quite fast processors. You are extremely unlikely to be concerned by computer limits on your software (that is, on the binary executable size). All the combined source code that you'll code in your entire professional life is much less than what a typical computer can fit (the rule of thumb is that developers are writing 20KLOC per year, so in all your life you'll only write one or two millions lines of code. For comparison, the Linux kernel is more than twenty millions lines of code and compiles into a few megabytes of binary program; the Firefox browser is about fifty millions lines of source code).

In the small [embedded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Embedded_system) computing area (e.g. [Arduino](http://arduino.cc/) like hardware & [IoT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_of_things) devices like smart light bulbs or connected tooth brushes) things are different: code size matters a lot, because you might have only a few dozen of kilobytes of code memory (and you can reach that limit). However, hardware is so cheap that using more powerful hardware ([RaspberryPi](http://raspberrypi.org/) like) makes more sense even in cheap embedded systems; so the trend is that code size matters less, even for embedded computing (but exceptions exist: [RFID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radio-frequency_identification) chips & [smart cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_card) are still very constrained on code size).

---

As a rule of thumb, you should not be concerned about using many header files and existing software components and libraries (and professionally you'll be required to use a lot of them). In some very specific cases and industries (the low-end spectrum of embedded computing), code size still matters a lot, and your employer will accept to spend labor costs to decrease it.
In other words, in most cases, software development costs (and time) are dominant. In some cases (embedded computing) they might not be, and other constraints could matter more.